# Import Wifi settings in my iOS device programmatically

Tags: ios, settings, wifi

My requirement is: I want the app user to be able to scan a barcode, which will contain the wifi configuration information, which automatically get saved in his devices' settings app[ofcourse with appropriate security], and his device gets connected to the very network.

Is there any way one can programatically feed wifi details into the device settings app and set the network up?

I know we can do this using iPhone Configuration Utility. However, I don't to take the user's device and install the certificate etc, I want it to happen automatically.

Is it possible?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a good idea, but on a non-jailbroken phone you can't do this; each app has it's own sandbox, and doesn't have access to system-level functions such as Network Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could programatically generate a xxxx.mobileconfig file that contains the wifi config information and then programatically navigate to a local url of that file.

Something like...  file://configs/xxxx.mobileconfig

Then iOS would prompt the user to see if they would like to install this mobile config profile.  If they say yes, the profile would be installed.

A possible gotcha would be serving a local xxxx.mobileconfig file may not have the appropriate mime-type and it may not prompt the user.

I know you said you know about the iPhone Configuration Utility.  This is sort of taking that approach, but doing it all programatically in the device.  I'm not sure if this will work.

Good Luck

Comment: do you know any links to tutorials that help me create .mobileconfig files "programatically"?